# Cronjob for 1st of January every year

Tags: cron

I am trying to get the correct cronjob time for 1st of January every year.

I thought about this: `0 0 1 1 *`

Can anybody tell me if it is correct?

Comment: here even technology should be specified because spring cron expression can configure seconds but linux cron is minute-based

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

Here is a quick chart you can use for future reference

```
# *    *    *    *    *  command to execute
# ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    │
# │    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday)
# │    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: Rolled back the edit that was approved as it was for a node based cron and not a unlix/linux based cron.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, and you can also use `@yearly` or `@annually` which are synonyms for `0 0 1 1 *`.

(This applies at least to many distributions, but check yours to be sure.)

See also: `man 5 crontab` and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks like the very new year midnight.