# @Scheduled(fixedRate = IsAYearPossible)

Tags: spring

One just very simple question: is a fixed rate of one year possible with

> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled ?

The schedule should run always at 01.01.xxxx 00:00

Comment: Just use `@Scheduled(cron="")` instead ... If you need cron expression for running every year on 1.1. take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502546/cronjob-for-1st-of-january-every-year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `fixed rate`, but `cron`, but yes, it is possible.

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 0 1 1 ?")
```

Meaning (in order):

- 0 -> 0 second
- 0 -> 0 minute
- 0 -> 0 hour
- 1 -> first day of the month
- 1 -> first month of the year
- ? -> regardless of which day of the week

Comment: I get an exception: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'checkFutureScheduleAndSetToSchedulePresence': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 0 0 1 1 ? *")

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Checking the official doc, the last param (year) does not need to be specified. I updated the answer.