# How to schedule a yearly cron job for a Laravel app on Linux AMI?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm trying to set up a cron job for the 1st of January on my AWS EC2 instance for `ec2-user`. 
When I do `crontab -u ec2-user -l`, it shows the following output:

```
* * * * * usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But even though the following was set up in `Kernel.php`, the job never fired:

```
protected $commands = [
    // Commands\Inspire::class,
    Commands\TestYearlyJob::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('table:test-yearly-job')->cron('0 0 1 1 *')
       ->timezone('Europe/London')
       ->appendOutputTo('../taskscheduler.log');
}
```

The command itself runs from Artisan (I've double checked), so its logic is fine.

I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with the `->yearly()->at()` scheduling option? Or perhaps with a `closure` truth test? But I'm not sure what to put in there for a `when()` statement. Please help.

Comment: Depending on where in the world you are maybe it's already past 00:00 January 1st, or it hasn't happened yet. How are you testing it?

Comment: After I SSH into my server (which is in the London region), it gives me the correct date for my timezone (Europe/London). Edit: it's past 00:00 1st Jan here.

Comment: @omrakhur How will you test the 1st Jan scenario again if its past 00:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling)

I noticed `cron` function has 6 stars. Try `->cron('0 0 1 1 * *')`. Also `yearly` has the same expression, so you can try either this `command(..)->yearly()->timezone(..)`

**Update**

The issue is missing `/` in `usr/bin/php`. `/usr/bin/php` fixed the issue

Comment: It's a bit confusing. On this page: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm
it says it has six asterisks. But not on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502546/cronjob-for-1st-of-january-every-year

Comment: @omrakhur yes it's confusing, may be the sixth star came in later. The stackoverflow, answered in 2013. I also dunno

Comment: @omrakhur Curious how are u testing it, because 1st Jan mid night is passed to London.

Comment: I'm testing it with `cron(*  *  *  *  *  *)`

Comment: @omrakhur ok noted. Can you run this command `usr/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run` and check if its triggering

Comment: It's strange as the log in /var/log/cron even listed it as a successful cron without the /. Oh well...