# How to set Cron Job in Cpanel?

Tags: java, php, android

I'm working on a Billing application where I am getting problem in setting Cron Job. I have one field in database called status which has value **1** for **OFF** and **0** for **ON**. I changed the value from 0 to 1. Now I want to change the value from 1 back to 0 when one complete year over.
Eg: I have changed the value from 0 to 1 on **10/1/2018** and I  want to change the value from 1 to 0 on **10/1/2019**

Please give the code for above cron job.

Comment: Do you want the cronjob for Java or PHP or Android ? Could you please specify what you want ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention..i want in PHP

Comment: i will post the current day acc.to that the value will change..

Answer (score 1):

in your crontab page use this code :

`0 0 10 1 * /usr/bin/php -f /usr/local/bin/run.php &> /dev/null`

notice that it will happen each 10/1/yearly

you need to change `/usr/bin/php` with your php interpreter path and `/usr/local/bin/run.php` is the file that want to change 1 to 0 or 0 to 1

and for more information about cron syntax you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502546/cronjob-for-1st-of-january-every-year)

Comment: thanks for reply..10/1/ is not fixed...i just given an example..date month and year may be anything..

Comment: oh it's ok, cron is just a simple plain text file, so you can easily generate it via every language like php like this :
`print "0 0 $day $month * /usr/bin/php ..."` but instead of print you need to wirte it into a file, check here https://askubuntu.com/questions/216692/where-is-the-user-crontab-stored please for knowing where is your cron files